ZFS: resilver restarted after the scan finished
As described here I had two dead drives on my raidz2 setup. I shut down the machine, replaced one drive, then booted up. My idea was to resilver disks one by one, but the resilver process for the remaining faulty disk started automatically, so I manually started it with zpool replace for the new drive. The faulty drive soon started to display read and CRC errors so the resilver stopped and the drive was marked FAULTED again, while the resilver of the new drive went on.
After several hours it happened that the resilver of the new drive started again from scratch. Looking at the zpool events, it seems that the end of the scan triggered the restart:
$ sudo zpool history -il
History for 'storage':
  .
  .
  .
2024-06-18.15:00:44 [txg:20528615] vdev attach replace vdev=/dev/sda1 for vdev=/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c500cadcc68f-part1 [on static-5-022.fi.infn.it]
2024-06-18.15:00:44 zpool replace storage 16811447176160354853 /dev/sda [user 0 (root) on static-5-022.fi.infn.it:linux]
2024-06-18.15:01:41 (1056ms) ioctl reopen
    input:
        scrub_restart: false
[user 0 (root) on static-5-022.fi.infn.it:linux]
2024-06-20.00:14:05 [txg:20547934] scan done errors=0 [on static-5-022.fi.infn.it]
2024-06-20.00:14:05 [txg:20547934] starting deferred resilver errors=0 [on static-5-022.fi.infn.it]
2024-06-20.00:14:11 [txg:20547935] scan setup func=2 mintxg=3 maxtxg=20528613 [on static-5-022.fi.infn.it]

Now the resilver and the scan are processing again:
$ zpool status -LP
  pool: storage
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices is currently being resilvered.  The pool will
        continue to function, possibly in a degraded state.
action: Wait for the resilver to complete.
  scan: resilver in progress since Thu Jun 20 00:14:11 2024
        107T scanned at 3.30G/s, 100T issued at 3.08G/s, 334T total
        3.73T resilvered, 29.91% done, 21:38:16 to go
config:

        NAME                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        storage                     DEGRADED     0     0     0
          raidz2-0                  DEGRADED     0     0     0
            replacing-0             DEGRADED     0     0     0
              16811447176160354853  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c500cadcc68f-part1
              /dev/sda1             ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)
            /dev/sdb1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdc1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdd1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sde1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdf1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdh1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdg1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdq1               FAULTED    228     0     3  too many errors
            /dev/sdl1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdn1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdp1               ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-1                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdz1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sds1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdt1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdv1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdw1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdi1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdj1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdk1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdm1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdo1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdr1               ONLINE       0     0     0
            /dev/sdx1               ONLINE       0     0     0
        logs
          /dev/nvme0n1p1            ONLINE       0     0     0
        cache
          /dev/sdu1                 ONLINE       0     0     0
          /dev/sdy1                 ONLINE       0     0     0

but I fear that for some reason at the end of the scan the resilver might be restarted again, in a infinite loop, so I need to understand what might have caused the restart.
I thought about the aborted resilvering of the faulty drive, but it happened long before the restart so I'm not sure.
Searching on the web I found that a similar problem was caused by the ZED on older versions of ZFS (I'm on 2.1.15-1 on Rocky Linux 9), but as far as I understand it should have been fixed.
So what should I expect? Is the faulty drive the real culprit, and could it repeat the offence even if it's been FAULTED since the start of the new resilver? Should I disable the ZED anyway as a precaution? Any other ideas?

Commercial help is available for this. It's tough to address this specific situation in a forum because every situation is unique.

Fortunately the second resilver attempt finished without problems.
